# cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information

Tags: .net

I'm getting this exception.. what could be the reason?

```
- 1/XX/2014 9:56:00 AM: 11253-Error creating configuration. 
Could not load configuration, Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information. 
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information. 

Application: xxxxxxxxx_xxxx.exe 
Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException 
Stack:
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to load a mixed-mode assembly from 2.0 or before into 4.0 you need to add the following entry into your app.config file

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
```

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx)

Comment: Well, I saw this topic before.. but can you kindly explain what causes the following situation, because the application was running pretty fine.. and they seems to be developed on 4.0 framework.. I don't see any 2.0 stuff.. care to define "mixed-mode assembly"

Comment: @user4127 a mixed mode assembly is one compiled with C++/CLI. The CLR deprecated the function the C++/CLI code potentially used to bring the CLR into a given process and replaced it with one that allows for side-by-side hosting.  This flag essentially disables side-by-side hostnig for apps that still use the old apis

Comment: is still not working.. am I missing any additional arguments?